# Using jekyll with --watch flag causing build errors

Tags: ruby, windows, jekyll

I am using Jekyll on Windows 8 to work on a small project for work.  So far I am loving Jekyll, but have encountered an issue when trying to serve my site with the `--watch` flag, which allows the site to update on refresh when changes are made to the code.

When I run my Jekyll sites I will open my `cmd` and `cd` to the proper directory.  Per the Jekyll docs, I will execute `chcp 65001` in the directory to change the encoding to UTF-8.  Now, when I run `jekyll serve -w` or `jekyll serve --watch` I get an error dump consisting of the following:

```
C:\Dropbox\Workbench\lunch-and-learn>jekyll serve -w
    Configuration file: C:/Dropbox/Workbench/lunch-and-learn/_config.yml
                Source: C:/Dropbox/Workbench/lunch-and-learn
           Destination: C:/Dropbox/Workbench/lunch-and-learn/_site
          Generating... done.
     Auto-regeneration: enabled
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:207:in `load_dependent_adapter'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapters/windows.rb:33:in `load_dependent_adapter'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:198:in `usable?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapters/windows.rb:25:in `usable?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:57:in `block in select_and_initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `select_and_initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listener.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listener.rb:283:in `setup'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.3.1/lib/listen/listener.rb:52:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:56:in `watch'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:8:in `process'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.1/bin/jekyll:97:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:66:in `run!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

It is worth noting that when I run the site with simply `jekyll serve`, without the `--watch` or `-w` flags, the site builds and serves just fine to port 4000.  However this is not ideal for development.

[Link to Jekyll Usage](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in the error message, `wdm` is not found.

First, update your gems

```
gem update
```

Then, manually install `wdm`

```
gem install wdm
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had gotten a response from a dev over on the Jekyll github with the same exact directions, and it worked like a charm.  I am a bit new to the whole Ruby thing, and was unable to interpret the error message to know what I was missing.  Thanks so much!